# "Assertion failed!" error when exiting program (HDF5 1.8.6)

Tags: c#, hdf5, assertion

I'm using HDF5 1.8.6 on a Windows7 32-bit system from a data acquisition C#/.Net application (using the HDFDotNet wrappers).

I've noticed a runtime error(AssertionFailed) popup when I exit my application after the following behavior:

1.) I open an HDF5 file on a USB drive (or network shared drive)
2.) I start sampling data and storing it to the HDF5 file.
3.) I (rudely) remove the USB drive (or disconnect the network shared drive)
4.) Write exceptions are handled (seemingly appropriately... no crashes)
5.) I close the application.

At this point I get the error, which mentions File:......\src\H5F.c (Line 1737) and "Expression: f->file_id>0"

I'm assuming the HDF5 library is trying to clean something up and is confused that it can't find a file it was using... but it seems it should still be able to recover when it can't.  Have I missed something?

Thanks!

Josh Anderson

Answer (score 0):

I bet the HDF5 has a close/exit/shutdown function that you should be calling before you exit.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response.  It looks as though the latest version (1.8.7) does indeed provide access to a method that does just this (H5.close).  It wasn't listed in the "Whats new in 1.8.7" list, but looking at the source it does indeed appear to be there.  I'll give it a try.  Thanks!

Comment: I was able to call the H5.close method (as mentioned previously) and it does seem to have solved the problem.  THanks!!

Comment: Spoke too soon:  I'm now getting a "System.AccessViolationException was unhandled" when calling H5.close (which just calls H5close in HDF5)